# Where is uint() function in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to compile a Qt application but I get an error:

`error: 'uint' was not declared in this scope`

The piece of code calling it:

`double Bi = gsl_ran_binomial_pdf(uint(i),t,uint(N-1));`

I realize this is a stupid question, but I can't find it anywhere (searched Qt source and standard lib) and it's non-googleable because of its name. I suspect its a some helper function in Qt framework.

Anyone knows where I can find the source?

Comment: You want to cast the value :
`(unsigned int)i`

Comment: `uint` is not a function.

Comment: Since I can't be sure what uint() does, I do not want to just cast the value..

Comment: The author forgot `#include <QtGlobal>`

Comment: thanks, will look into `QtGlobal`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely that `uint` in not a function, but rather a typedef (or alias) for the type `unsigned int`. Somewhere in the source there will be a line like

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
```

or (C++11-style)

```
using uint = unsigned int;
```

This tells the compiler that when you type `uint`, it should substitute the name of the built-in type `unsigned int`.

Now, when you say `uint(i)`, it's not a function call but rather a *function-style cast*, which converts the value to an `unsigned int`. You could equally say

```
static_cast<uint>(i)
```

to get the same effect.

Comment: This is exactly it. Found it in Qt source.